# gnome-terminal issue

Tags: 12.04, gnome

When I run `gnome-terminal` I get following error:

```
GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/BPT trap
```

Anyone has idea what is missing? where can I find it.

Comment: In 20.04, there are two other terminal apps. Open dash and type "term", you will get UXTerm and XTerm apps. Check if any of those are working..?

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall `gsettings-desktop-schemas`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

**Source:** http://aptosid.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=2246